# Kibana - Elastic - Fleet - APM - failed to listen:listen tcp bind: can't assign requested address

Tags: kubernetes, elastic-stack, elastic-apm, fleet

Having setup Kibana and a fleet server, I now have attempted to add APM.
When going through the general setup - I forever get an error no matter what is done:

```
failed to listen:listen tcp *.*.*.*:8200: bind: can't assign requested address
```

This is when following the steps for setup of APM having created the fleet server.
This is all being launched in Kubernetes and the documentation has been gone through several times to no avail.

We did discover that we can hit the

> /intake/v2/events

etc endpoints when shelled into the container but 404 for everything else. Its close but no cigar so far following the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, the general walk through is soon to be depreciated in its current form as is.
And setup is far far simpler in a helm file where its actually possible to configure kibana  with package ref for your named apm service.

> ```
> xpack.fleet.packages:
>   - name: system
>     version: latest
>   - name: elastic_agent
>     version: latest
>   - name: fleet_server
>     version: latest
>   - name: apm
>     version: latest
> ```

```
    xpack.fleet.agentPolicies:
  - name: Fleet Server on ECK policy
    id: eck-fleet-server
    is_default_fleet_server: true
    namespace: default
    monitoring_enabled:
      - logs
      - metrics
    unenroll_timeout: 900
    package_policies:
    - name: fleet_server-1
      id: fleet_server-1
      package:
        name: fleet_server
  - name: Elastic Agent on ECK policy
    id: eck-agent
    namespace: default
    monitoring_enabled:
      - logs
      - metrics
    unenroll_timeout: 900
    is_default: true
    package_policies:
      - name: system-1
        id: system-1
        package:
          name: system
      - package:
          name: apm
        name: apm-1
        inputs:
        - type: apm
          enabled: true
          vars:
          - name: host
            value: 0.0.0.0:8200
```

Making sure these are set in the kibana helm file will allow any spun up fleet server to automatically register as having APM.

The missing key in seemingly all the documentation is the need of a APM service.
The simplest example of which is here:

[Example yaml scripts](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/2.3/config/recipes/elastic-agent/fleet-apm-integration.yaml)